# Disable Touchpad while typing without having synaptics

Tags: windows-8.1, toshiba-laptop, synaptics-touchpad, ultrabook

I want to disable the touchpad while I am typing but my computer does not have the software to disable it. How can I go about this?

I have a 64-bit Toshiba Kira UltraBook running Windows 8.1 Pro Model #:PSUC2U-003008

Things I've tried:

- It does not have have Synaptics installed. I checked, no extra tab or options on "Mouse" under Control Panel. It purchased it new.
- Toshiba support does not have a Synaptics driver for my computer. I looked.
  http://support.toshiba.com/support/driversResults?freeText=PSUC2U-003008
- The Synaptics website itself does have the driver but when I try to install it, it fails and does not display any help messages ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biPkF.png)). I used the below link.

  - http://synaptics.com/resources (Windows 8/7/XP/Vista 64/32-bit Edition v17.0.19)

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Is it actually a Synaptics touchpad? Might be Elan or ALPS.

Comment: How would I check that, my good sir?

Answer (score 0):

[TouchFreeze](http://touchfreeze.net/) automatically disables the touchpad when you're typing.

Note I haven't ever used this software myself but [the VirusTotal result](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/95725bec7c7c55c72ad4c78528a0b3e21c93466c86e5766a3b998bb5ea09998d/analysis/1455358418/) reports all clear.

Source: [The Windows Club article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/cursor-jumps-moves-randomly-while-typing)